# jquery ajax load content from a button that is inside the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery and ajax to load pages without reloading the entire website and I ran into a problem.
This is the jquery script:

```
$(function(){
$("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    //get the link location that was clicked
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

    //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
    if(pageurl!=window.location){
    $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
        $('#main-wrap').html(data);
    }});
    }
    //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
    if(pageurl!=window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
    }
    return false;  
   });
     });

   /* the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without reload*/
      $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
$.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
    $('#main-wrap').html(data);
}});
});
```

and the html code is something like this:

```
<div class="nav"><a href="example1.html" rel="tab">Page 1</a></div>
<div class="ajax-content">
<div class="title"><a href="title_page.html" rel="tab">Title</a></div>
</div>
```

Now if I click "Page 1" that is outside the div where the ajax content is loaded it's working but if I click "Title" that is inside the div, the whole page is reloaded(ajax not working).
It's possible to make that "Title" link(which is inside the div where the ajax content is loaded) to work?

Comment: Is this exactly how you are binding the click handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is that you are adding the event handler to all `a[rel='tab']` on document ready, but you are loading the target `<a>` after the fact. That means that they will not have the event handler bound to their click. You should use something like `live` or more importantly `on`. The importance is event delegation, where you would use something like:

```
$("#container").on("click", "a[rel='tab']", function () {
    // Your code
});
```

This way, any `a[rel='tab']` that is removed or added inside of the `#container` element has this event handler attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Set your href attribute to # and add a return false;

Try this:

```
<div class="title"><a href="#" rel="tab" onclick="return false;">Title</a></div>
```

Comment: e.preventDefault();  should prevent the href attribute from doing anything anyway I think

Comment: Ah yes, didn't see that. My fault.

Comment: @soupy1976 Yeah, and so does `return false;` from the event handler :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just ditch the inner link if you're already scripting it, and instead put the url in a data-url attribute. Then you don't have to worry about covering your tracks with any default behavior. Your div would look like this:

```
<div class="title" id='link_btn' data-url="title_page.html">Title</div>
```

Then rework your code like this:

```
("#link_btn").click(function(){  

    //get the link location that was clicked
    pageurl = $(this).attr('data-url');
```

Data attributes are a great way to pass data between elements and your script. You just have to be careful when you create them as special characters and quotes can mess them up and make them unreadable.